# How to fix misplacement of view outside of the RecyclerView until user scrolls the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

This is the problem I have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zlaR.jpg

The AdView that I have anchored to the bottom of the layout will be slightly pulled out of place and will only come back to its intended place when the user scrolls through the RecyclerView again.

The activity uses two fragments, one for the banner at the bottom and another one on top for the rest of views so when the user clicks a ViewHolder the upper fragment is replaced.

I have tried to use methods such as .scrollToView to force the RecyclerView to move, but it kept the misplacement of the banner. ONLY when the user does scroll comes back into the right place.

I have checked that if instead of replacing the upper fragment the user was taken to a different activity and then the back button was pressed, this problem would not happen. But I need to use a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating seperate fragment for banner in Activity. you should use this code technique in your fragmentActivity. use relative layout for top view in activity then add bannerView with specific height and set alignParentBottom to true. then add another layout which contain your recyclerview fragment and set this property (layoutAbove and pass the addview id to id). it will place exact top of the banner.